# Wordpress Few styles adding inside body tag

Tags: wordpress, header, styles

W3C validation shows me that two css files `mediaelementplayer.min.css & wp-mediaelement.css` loading inside body tag

Below the code (on wp-includes/script-loader.php) adding these stylesheets,

```
$styles->add( 'mediaelement', "/hr-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min.css", array(), '2.13.0' );
$styles->add( 'wp-mediaelement', "/hr-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.css", array( 'mediaelement' ) );
```

Is anyone know the reason why this particular 2 css files adding with body tag ?

Is any way to call those inside head tag ?

Answer (score 2):

With the use of HTML5, it has introduced many new inbuilt elements for more SEO semantic purpose and ease of use too.

Some of them I can listed below:

- section
- article
- address
- video
- audio

Video and Audio tags are we can consider as media tags. To use them is very easy and convenient.
Previously we need to use FLASH or SILVERLIGHT object to create a player while HTML5's media element provide inbuilt support for video and audio players.

The files you have mentioned would have styling for these players.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's all correct. The only problem is that i need to load all css within head tag not inside body tag.

Comment: If you want to load them into HEAD instead of body, you should use jQuery Append function using IF / ELSE condition. I have followed same way in Liferay CMS for backend customization. It really works.

Answer (score 0):

Vin if you are using a packaged Wordpress theme, then the developer has added these for styling aspects of that theme.  If you are not using the MediaElement javascript player then you could safely remove those CSS calls.